# plugin not loaded or not available: use the adoonly option

Tags: stata

```
mvtobit ( CHILDT_FAT = INCOME ) ( HOUSET_FAT = INCOME ) ( DISCT_FAT = INCOME ) ( CHILDT_MOT = INCOME ) ( HOUSET_MOT = INCOME ) ( DISCT_MOT = INCOME )


Running Stata version 9 or higher. You should consider installing cmp.



Fitting univariate models (Tobit or continuous) to get starting values

Maximum # of censored equations is 6

Draws (Halton/pseudo random) are being made:

Created 5 Halton draws per equation for 6 dimensions. Number of initial draws dropped per dimension = 0 . Primes used:

   2   3   5   7  11  13
```

I keep getting this error

```
plugin not loaded or not available: use the adoonly option
r(199);
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough, so what is the question?

Comment: How to get over this error so that the stata mvtobit program runs smoothly.

Comment: Use the `adoonly` option.

Comment: Yes, it got solved. Thanks